# Make image center without display block

Tags: html, css, center

My html:

```
<p>
    <a href="#">
        <img src="image.png" />
    </a>
</p>

<p>Some text</p>
```

I want to move image to center without making it block. With block link goes clickable in all width.

Tried:

```
img{
    margin:0 auto;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

but it doesn't work.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/narekmarkosyan/9653Y/1/).

[Fiddle with centered image but wrong link](http://jsfiddle.net/narekmarkosyan/9653Y/2/).

Image width can be different.

Any idea how to make image center and leave clickable area only on image?

Comment: You want text also in center?

Comment: @Hiral, no only image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set this CSS for the `a` tag:

```
a{
  margin:0 auto;
  display:table;
}
```

The demo **http://jsfiddle.net/9653Y/4/**

Comment: Greate, it works. Didn't think to try other display attributes.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<p id="imgPara">
    <a href="#">
        <img id="image" src="http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/images/feather.gif" />
    </a>
</p>
<p>Some text</p>

#imgPara{
text-align: center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Shashi0812/YAusb/

Comment: Only image, not text.

Answer (score 0):

Align parent of `img` to center.

HTML:

```
<p class="center">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/images/feather.gif" />
    </a>
</p>
```

CSS:

```
.center{text-align:center;}
```

[**Here is the updated fiddle**.](http://jsfiddle.net/9653Y/6/)

Comment: I have no access to `<p>`

Comment: it generates with WYSIWYG.

Answer (score -1):

change margin to 50%

```
 img{
        margin:0 50%;
        display:inline-block;
    }
```

Comment: That will not work. As this will take the 50% of the main window and then move the image to some side..